# switching global planner

Tags: navigation, navfn, move-base, carrot-planner, baseglobalplanner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

In nav_core default global planner is navfn, but I want to change it to carrot planner or something else (in future it will be my global planner). What I have to change and where?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12694/switching-global-planner/) by [Jacek](https://answers.ros.org/users/1670/jacek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-01-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jacek](https://answers.ros.org/users/1670/jacek/) on 2012-01-19**:
It was first thing I've done. Now it looks like this:
private_nh.param("base_global_planner", global_planner, std::string("carrot_planner/CarrotPlanner"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll have to change the `base_global_planner` parameter of move_base. See the [move_base docs](http://ros.org/wiki/move_base) for more details.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The string you edited is the default value for the parameter. You could have a parameter file loaded, or defined that parameter in a .launch script, which defines the base_global_planner as navfn, therefore it never uses your default value.

Try finding if you got a parameter like this set up in some config file or launch script, and change it to your carrot planner. Generally you shouldn't need to edit the code, you can adjust most navigation settings using parameters.

---

Originally posted by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) with karma: 1909 on 2012-01-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2012-01-19**:
I'm going to go further and say that you should *never* edit anything installed in /opt/ros, because it will get overwritten when you upgrade your ROS packages, and the packages in /opt/ros at configured not to rebuild when you run rosmake, to save compilation time, so it ignores code changes.